# Extracting from Windows Zip file using Java

Tags: deflate

I am completely frustrated now. I have a zip file that is created using Windows 7 64bit compression. The original file is more than 3GB. The zip file is 32MB. However, the compression used by Windows 7 is ENHANCED_DEFLATE. I tried TrueZip, Apache compress and also JDK 1.8. None of them could extract the file from the zip. All of them gave an error of "not supported compression method 9". Is there any library or any other way to extract the file from the zip?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think that's specific to Windows, FYI.  The file is compressed using the built in shell functionality of Windows?  Are you sure its not password protected / encrypted?

Comment: Quite likely your file is damaged. Generally speaking, the compression ratio is so high is way off the chart.

Comment: That compression ratio is close to the maximum possible with deflate, but does not indicate corruption.

Comment: I was able to unzip it on Unix by using unzip command. But TrueZip and Apache Compress return "non supported compression method 9". JDK 1.8 returns java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad compression method).

Answer (score 1):

You can interface to [this C code, infback9](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/infback9), which decompresses method 9 compressed data. You will need to roll your own zip file decoding to get you to the compressed data for each entry.